# How to have a fixed time populated in a date/time formula field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I have to create a date/time formula field, whose date value will come from a date/time field. However, I want the time to be always 5:00 am. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula:

DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))+ ' 05:00:00')

Where CreatedDate is your DT field. This will be in GMT though, so you have have to adjust for your time zone.

Comment: Mine is GMT -7, how can I adjust that?

Comment: Try DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))+ ' 05:00:00') - (7/24)

Comment: For GMT + 5:30, DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))+ ' 05:00:00') +(5.30/24) is it the right adjustment? –